# How can I load external snippet files into Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, snippets

I have a bunch of useful snippets that I want to share with my team. Ideally I'd put these on our network storage and have everyone's Visual Studio Code installation point to that file/folder, but as far as I understand VSCode can only load snippet files directly from the `%appdata%\Code\User\snippets` folder.

Is there a setting that would allow me to load snippets from other folders?

Unfortunately we work on multiple projects, so using workspace-scoped snippets in the `.vscode` folders only helps us a little bit. Whenever we have a new project we have to copy the entire folder over and this leads to inconsistencies whenever a snippet gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding a symbolic link to your shared folder inside
`%appdata%\Code\User\snippets`.

The article
[Adding Snippets to Visual Studio Code](https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customization/userdefinedsnippets/)
contains more information about sharing your snippets as a
snippet extension, using the `yo code` extension generator.
This method might not fit here, because it's basically copying
the snippets, but the symbolic link approach might help.

See the article
[The Complete Guide to Creating Symbolic Links (aka Symlinks) on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).

Comment: Ideally I'd just use a folder config somewhere hidden in code, but since that doesn't exist, a symbolic link will suffice I guess. At least it's something I can solve with a simple batch script.

Comment: The idea of sharing through an extension is also pretty good - I could easily keep stuff up to date using our private NPM repo that way.